# I am using https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension my app got crash(keep stoping) for bot ios and android

Tags: react-native, share-extension

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension

please check i have followed all steps but, i got crash issue in iOS and Android both

is there any other working module for that? it will be really helpful for me thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.